# count the occurrences of certain variables dyplr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a flight dataset using `dplyr` library. I am struggling by trying to group the 2 delays (`WEATHER_DELAY`, `NAS_DELAY`) based on the `UNIQUE CARRIER`.

That gives me :

```
UNIQUE_CARRIER WEATHER_DELAY NAS_DELAY
1 9E                               
2 9E                               
3 9E                                            
4 9A
5 9A
```

But I would like to get as below:

```
UNIQUE_CARRIER WEATHER_DELAY NAS_DELAY
1 9E                 
2 9A                        
3 9B
```

I wrote the following code:

```
complete.data %>%
filter(WEATHER_DELAY!=0, NAS_DELAY!=0) %>%
select(UNIQUE_CARRIER, WEATHER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY) %>%
group_by(UNIQUE_CARRIER) %>% 
as.data.frame() %>%
add_tally()
```

Comment: No idea what you need but maybe `complete.data %>% filter(blah blah) %>% count(UNIQUE_CARRIER, WEATHER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY)`

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you follow [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `tally` will count unique elements. From the sound of it, `WEATHER_DELAY` and  `NAS_DELAY` need to be summed. If so, try `group_by(UNIQUE_CARRIER) %>% summarise_at(vars(WEATHER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY),sum)`